# How to change the colour of the bounding box in opencv SelectROI function

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I been looking everywhere on how to change the color of the bounding box that comes with the SelectROI function.

```
bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)
```

The default bounding box is of the blue color but the videos I am doing on need a different colour such as bright red or orange.

I would really appreciate if anyone could point out on how to do it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can change the colour if the `selectROI()` method directly. As you observed the default colour is blue, which is hardcoded in the method by creating a new rectangle, see [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/highgui/src/roiSelector.cpp#L41):

```
// draw the selected object
rectangle(selectorParams.image, selectorParams.box, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, 1);
```

You could adjust the source in this line and rebuild your library it get a new default color or even add it to the params.

You might even want to create a pull request while your at it, I don't think it is unreasonable to add this option to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try cv2.rectangle().
Here is the link for the syntax : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-rectangle-method/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thx for the answerBut I dont know the cordinates to choose the bounding box and the selectroi does that.

Comment: The coordinates are represented by bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[2], bbox[3]